# After moment format it shows completely different value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3, momentjs

Could you tell me why this strange behavior? Is that due to incoming date format issue or else?

*.html*

```
 <ion-datetime displayFormat="D MMM, YYYY" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" 
[ngModel]="data?.dueOn" (ngModelChange)="data.dueOn=$event;"
name="dueOn" class="date-picker-right-align"></ion-datetime>
```

*.ts*

```
auditLogDueOnDays = `Payment due date changed from 
${moment(this.oldTransactionValue.dueOn).format("d MMM YY")} to 
${moment(data.dueOn).format("d MMM YY")} `;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my BAD :(

> Day of Week   d   0 1 ... 5 6

I must use:

> Day of Month  D   1 2 ... 30 31

```
auditLogDueOnDays = `Payment due date changed from 
${moment(this.oldTransactionValue.dueOn).format("D MMM YY")} to 
${moment(data.dueOn).format("D MMM YY")} `;
```